# Use function spplot

Tags: raster, polygon, r, sp

Does anybody know how to plot with "spplot" fuction two elements of diferents classes?. One element from "SpatialPolygonDataFrame" class and other from "raster" class.

Comment: do you **have** to use `spplot`?

Comment: No, maybe with ggplot. I have to get something like this https://www.google.com/search?q=spplot+levelplot&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwialIishsfKAhUK7SYKHVoTACcQ_AUICCgC&biw=1525&bih=745&dpr=0.9#imgrc=88p2k_trW9ok6M%3A

Comment: So just a raster with a polygon overlaid? You don't want to colour the polygons?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this quite easily with base graphics, I don't see a real need for `spplot` or `ggplot`:

Sample data: Spain and a random raster:

```
require(raster)
es = getData("GADM", country="ESP",level=1)
es =es[-14,] # drop canary islands
r = raster(extent(es),ncol=200,nrow=200)
r[]=runif(200*200)
```

Plot the raster and add the polygons - the alternative clips the raster to the Spanish polygons using the `mask` function:

```
plot(r)  # or try: plot(mask(r,es))
plot(es, add=TRUE)
```

Here's the clipped version:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But the problem is when I try to plot a SpatialPolygonDataFrame element with raster or SpatialGridDataFrame. I always get an error like this: "Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = c(52.6195687909829, 52.6845097109409,  : 
  replacement has 64 rows, data has 672"

Comment: That sounds like a separate problem - can you make a reproducible example as a new question?

Comment: Yes, give me a moment.

Comment: Look, this is the question. Thanks for your help. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/178191/spplot-spatialpolygondataframe-and-spatialgriddataframe

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with `spplot`, you could e.g. use `layer` from **latticeExtra** to add 'Spatial*' objects to an existing plot. Based on the code provided by @Spacedman, this would look as follows.

```
## load package
library(latticeExtra)

## plot raster and add polygons
spplot(r, scales = list(draw = TRUE), 
       col.regions = terrain.colors(100), at = seq(0, 1, .01)) + 
  layer(sp.polygons(es, lwd = 2))
```

[image: spplot]

Answer (score 0):

Using only ssplot with sp.layout, without latticeExtra gives the same result:

```
## Define how the polygon should appear
borders <- list("sp.polygons", es, fill = "transparent", col = 'black', first = FALSE)

## plot both raster and polygon
spplot(r,
       sp.layout = borders,
       col.regions = terrain.colors(100), at = seq(0, 1, .01),
       scales = list(draw = TRUE))
```

[image]